# Notes taken on iPad occur blurry on mac

Tags: ipad, icloud, notes.app

I have taken a handwritten note using my Apple pencil.  I sync the notes via iCloud.  Some of the notes appear not full-width in Notes on Mac; rather, they are displayed very small and blurry.  The blur stays if I export the note to a PDF file.  Strangely, this only happens for some notes.  On the iPad, all notes look the same.  I haven't figured out yet what distinguishes these from those notes.

Faulty:
[image: faulty behaviour]
Correct:
[image: correct behaviour]
I am using
Notes on Mac: 4.6
MacOS: 10.14.6
iOS: 13.1

Comment: Could be something in Mojave. I'm running High Sierra and that problem doesn't show up.